# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. AWS

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded a static website in html, css and javascript in AWS s3. Ive already enabled **CORS** in the API and seem to be getting the correct request when invoking the URL. [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f06bj.png)

However, im still facing this `Access-Control-Allow_Origin` which is preventing the transition of pages in my website.

Ive been using a CORS extension in Chrome while developing the website, and it worked. Now that its in s3 I am having a bit of trouble configuring it.

**Update**: Here is the response that I get from creating the XMLHttp [request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpChD.png). Can someone also explain to me why the chrome extension eliminates this error?

API Gateway OPTIONS Method Response:[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sUH0.png)

API Gateway OPTIONS Integration Response: [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOOJU.png)

My JavaScript Code [img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHAZf.png)

Comment: How did you enable CORS?

Comment: Follow this guide to enable CORS on your S3 bucket: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: I enabled CORS in my lambda function through the API gateway. It generated an OPTIONS method that has the configurations. @AyushGupta

Comment: What are the headers and status-code, when invoke this request by an REST-Client?

Comment: Picture in edited response @alwe

Comment: yes, this looks good. But my question was what the values are of the current request (network tab in the dev web console). If the resonse is not a 200, then no cors header will be sent. I just want to be sure, that we can exclude this error vertor.

Comment: yes, this looks good. But my question was what the values are of the current request (network tab in the dev web console). If the resonse is not a 200, then no cors header will be sent. I just want to be sure, that we can exclude this error vertor.